# Laravel 6.x がサポートするのは PHP 8.0 系まででしょうか？

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 6.x がサポートするのは PHP 8.0 系までということで認識合っているでしょうか？

**[6.x] Full PHP 8.0 Support #33388**
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/33388

8.1 系もサポートするよ、などのレファレンスがありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こちらのページにサポートバージョンが記述されています

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#support-policy

6系はPHP 8.0までになります

Comment: そうだったんですね！知らずにすみません、ありがとうございました！！